# Checkbox Values Being Ignored In MVC Array

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View that allows the user to add multiple parts into the system at once. This can be done by clicking an "Add" button, which adds another row of input fields:

```
function AddItem() {
        $("#PartItems").append("<tr>" +
                                    "<td><input type='text' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].Code' style='width:100px' /></td>" +
                                    "<td><input type='text' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].ManufacturersCode' style='width:100px' /></td>" +
                                    "<td><input type='text' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].Name' style='width:280px' /></td>" +
                                    "<td style='min-width:100px;'><span class='inputunits'>@ViewBag.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol<input type='text' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].Cost' style='width:75px' /></span></td>" +
                                    "<td style='min-width:50px;'><input type='hidden' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].IsStockItem' value='false' /><input type='checkbox' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].IsStockItem' value='true' /></td>" +
                                    "<td style='min-width:70px;'><span class='StockInput'><input type='text' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].QuantityInStock' style='width:50px' value='1' /></span></td>" +
                                    "<td style='min-width:70px;'><span class='StockInput'><input type='text' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].LeadTime' style='width:50px' value='1' /></span></td>" +
                               "</tr>");

        itemCount++;
    }
```

Once submitted, the fields are mapped to a list of StockItems:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<Models.StockItem> Part)
```

This appears to be working fine for all the fields, except the "IsStockItem" boolean. Is there something special that needs to be done when mapping to a boolean in an array?

I have tried the above html code with/without specifying a value for the checkbox, and also without the hidden field, with no joy.

Comment: yes, I have tried removing the hidden input. This is the way MVC creates checkbox fields when using binding - a checkbox doesnt submit a value when it is not checked, hence the need for the hidden field. (the checkbox will override it when selected).

Comment: If the value is `true`, shouldn't it be checked? Have you tried adding `checked:'checked'` to the checkbox?

Comment: the value is only submitted when the checkbox is checked. Adding `checked="checked"` just makes the checkbox checked by default. Even after submitting, it still doesnt map the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have been unable to solve the issue with submitting checkboxes - I have managed to come up with a workaround. I have renamed the hidden field to "IsStockItem" so that this is mapped to the class in MVC, and instead added jQuery code to the checkbox to set the value of the hidden field when the value is changed.

```
"<td style='min-width:50px;'><input type='hidden' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].IsStockItem' value='false' /><input type='checkbox' name='Part[" + itemCount + "].StockItemCheckbox'  /></td>" +
```

and the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name*=StockItemCheckbox]').live("click", function () {
        row = $(this).parent().parent();

        if (this.checked) {
            $(".StockInput", $(row)).show("slow");
            $("input[name*=IsStockItem]", $(row)).val("true");
        }
        else {
            $(".StockInput", $(row)).hide("slow");
            $("input[name*=IsStockItem]", $(row)).val("false");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried to change the field "IsStockItem" to just "StockItem", and update the getter/setter for the matching class?

Is the current getter for the field isIsStockItem()?

Comment: the field it is bound to is "IsStockItem", so it should map just fine.